# Gravity Form Post Data from One Form to use in shortcode on another page

Tags: google-maps, gravity-forms-plugin

I need some help with a Gravity Forms issue. Currently I have 2 fields, a latitude and longitude field. The user enters those items, submits, then I need to re-direct the user to another page where a Google map gets plotted with a pin reflecting the latitude and longitude that the user entered.

Gravity Forms admin posted a solution that was kind of along these lines, however, I cannot for the life of me get it to work. It is at http://www.gravityhelp.com/forums/topic/google-map-on-preview-and-singlephp for those of you who have access to the forum.

Basically, I want to pass the user entries over to a page and then populate a short code on the page (Gravity Forms admin said he had to do this via the template file) which will produce the Google map (using a mapping plugin like http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-google-maps-shortcode/)

So like this: user on page 1, user enters lat/long data, submits, after submission user is redirected to page 2 where there is the Google Map plugin and shortcode, shortcode parameters for latitude and longitude are populated by the user's submitted entries from page 1, map gets displayed.

I have tried this solution below to get the parameters out of the form after submission, but this is as good as I have thus far and don't know how to make this thing work (added to my functions.php file and yes, I know it is referring to a specific form # 5):

```
add_action('gform_after_submission_5', 'after_submission_value', 10, 2);
function after_submission_value($entry, $form){

$latitudeval = $entry['2'];
$longitudeval= $entry['3'];  }
```

As a follow up question, using this method above, what happens if 2 people at the exact same time enter parameters? Just curious.

I am open to any other methods, or suggestions too for a solution.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you use Street, City, State, Zip, or Country instead of latitude/longitude (or map the latter to the former), then you can use this plugin:

https://www.danielabernathy.com/plugins/gravity-forms-google-maps-add-on/